# Projectile motion on an inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

Two parallel straight lines are inclined to the horizontal at angle $\theta$. A particle is projected from a point midway between them so as to graze one of the lines and strikes the other at a right angle. Show that if $\alpha$ is angle between the direction of projection and either of lines, then $\tan\alpha=(2^{1/2} - 1)\cot\theta$ .

My work: I applied the equation of motion at maximum height to find the distance between the lines and then applied equation of motion when it hits the second parallel line or incline at got the value of time of flight. Finally I used the equation of motion for y-axis direction and got the equation: $\tan\alpha= \cot\theta(\cot\theta \cot\alpha - 2)$. I am not able to proceed this equation because I am unable to find the relation between $\theta$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: I want to know how I can get the relation between angle a and theta to proceed my equation which i have got

Comment: You write *"I applied the equation of motion at maximum height to find..."*. But why did you use maximum height? Is there even a guarantee that the particle reaches maximum height on the described path? What if it was projected *downward* in the first place? Don't try to shoehorn techniques from other solutions into places where they don't belong. Instead, think how you could express those parallel lines as equations in space, and build geometric limits on the lines from there.

Comment: Because its given in the question that the particle grazes the first parallel line and falls perpendicularly on other parallel line or incline and as the particle was thrown from midpoint so the stone cannot be thrown downwards. This is what i know.. #dmckee

Comment: Have you drawn the geometry? Does the grazing of the uppermost line happen at maximum height?  You should be able to convince yourself that throwing downward is not allowed in this case, but you should also be able to convince yourself that maximum height is the wrong condition to use. (Aside use '@' to direct a comment to another user, not '#'.)

Comment: I meant if I draw a line through midpoint or I can say point of projection parallel to the other inclines then from that incline grazing will occur at maximum height

Comment: Rohit, if you are still having difficulty, please post your working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a relation between $\theta$ and $\alpha$.  If this is correct, all you need to do is to rearrange it.  If it is not possible to rearrange it to get the given relation, then either your equation is wrong, or the given equation is wrong, or both.

If the particle grazes the upper plane at maximum height, where the velocity vector is horizontal, then the planes must be horizontal.  The falling particle must then strike the lower plane vertically.  This can only happen if the particle is projected vertically.

So grazing at maximum height requires $\theta = 0$ and $\alpha = 90^\circ$, no other combinations being possible.  It seems your equation might be wrong.

**However**, perhaps you are using co-ordinate axes which are parallel and perpendicular to the inclined planes.  In this frame of reference the particle **does** graze the upper plane at maximum height.  The difficulty of this approach is transforming the equation of the trajectory to these axes - although, this may not be necessary.

---

Because time (eg time of flight, speed and $g$) do not feature in the answer, the problem can be solved using only co-ordinate geometry.  Inverting the parabola and placing the vertex at the origin, the eqn of the trajectory is $4ay=x^2$ which has the parametric form $x=2at, y=at^2$ for some parameters $a>0$ and $-\infty < t < +\infty$.

The parabola is intersected by 3 parallel, equidistant lines at points with parameters $p, q, r$ where $q>p>0$ and $r<0$. The tangent to the parabola at a point with parameter p has slope p.  The tangent at r is normal to that at p so $pr=-1$.

Using the fact that the lines are equidistant you should (I think) be able to express the tangent at $q=\tan(\theta + \alpha)$ in terms of $p=\tan\theta$, hence derive a relation between $\tan\theta$ and $\tan\alpha$.

---